# html property is hidden just by referencing the hidden property of extjs

Tags: html, extjs

I have an issue with one of my ExtJS items. I have a list of items most of which are buttons with icons, but one is an href with a bit of html. I want to hide these items whenever an external property is disabled.

To do that, inside of the items I have been using the following

```
hidden: !this.external.prop.enabled
```

For the buttons this works fine. They are visible when the prop is enabled and totally hidden when the prop is disabled. The item that uses html however, is hidden every time. Even when I set hidden to false like so

```
hidden:false
```

the Item looks like this

```
                {
                xtype: 'box',
                margin:'5',
                autoEl:{
                    tag: 'a',
                    hidden: !this.external.prop.enabled,
                    href: BaseURL + Glue.uiConfig.url.launchProp,
                    html: 'Launch Prop'
                }
            },
```

These items are all in the same array so I'm not sure why they are exhibiting different behavior. Has anyone ever experienced something like this? Do I need to provide more information?

thanks,

Comment: Perhaps try to put the `hidden` outside the `autoEl` config?

Comment: Thanks! That solved it! Post it as an answer if you want the check mark/recognition! Plus, I can't believe I put the code there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `hidden` outside the `autoEl` config.